# RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem) already deleted

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a class frame renderer

```
class FrameRenderer():

    simulation = None 
    scene = None 
    timer = None 

    def __init__(self, simulation, scene):
        self.simulation = simulation
        self.scene = scene
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.nextFrame)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000/30)# 30 Frames per second  

    #Render one time step 
    def nextFrame(self):
        for food in self.simulation.food:
            food.xPos = food.xPos + randint(-1,1)
            food.yPos = food.yPos + randint(-1,1)
            if food.pixmap:
                food.pixmap.setPos(food.xPos, food.yPos)

    def start(self):
        self.timer.start()

    def pause(self):
        self.timer.stop()
```

For a test I'm just making my pixmaps move randomly. It is invoked from a second class SimulationView

```
class SimulationView():

    mainWindow = None
    graphicsScene = None 
    simWindow = None
    simulation = None
    isSimulating = False  
    simulationStarted = False 
    frameRenderer = None 
    beginSimulationButton = None 
    cancelSimulationButton = None 
    toggleSimulationButton = None 
    foodSlider = None 
    BUFFER = 10 #ensure we don't drop items too close to the extremes of the scene 


    def __init__(self, mainWindow):

        self.mainWindow = mainWindow

        self.simWindow = mainWindow.simulation_window

        #connect QWidgets to functions 
        self.beginSimulationButton = mainWindow.begin_simulation_button
        self.beginSimulationButton.clicked.connect(self.simulate)

        self.cancelSimulationButton = mainWindow.cancel_simulation_button
        self.cancelSimulationButton.clicked.connect(self.cancelSimulation)

        self.toggleSimulationButton = mainWindow.toggle_simulation_button
        self.toggleSimulationButton.clicked.connect(self.toggleSimulation)

        self.foodSlider = mainWindow.food_slider

    def createGraphicsScene(self):
        #create new scene 
        self.graphicsScene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsScene.setSceneRect(self.simWindow.x(), self.simWindow.y(), self.simWindow.width() - self.BUFFER, self.simWindow.height() - self.BUFFER)
        self.simWindow.setScene(self.graphicsScene)

    #draw the food items to the screen and create new food objects 
    def drawFood(self, foodAmount):
        for _ in range(foodAmount):
            food_x = randint(self.BUFFER, self.graphicsScene.width() - self.BUFFER)
            food_y = randint(self.BUFFER, self.graphicsScene.height() - self.BUFFER)
            newFood = Food(food_x,food_y)
            self.simulation.addFood(newFood)
            self.graphicsScene.addItem(newFood.pixmap)
            newFood.pixmap.setPos(food_x, food_y)

    #call the correct function based on the simulation state
    def simulate(self):
        self.start()
        self.isSimulating = True 
        self.simulationStarted = True

    #start the simulation 
    def start(self):
        self.createGraphicsScene()
        self.simulation = Simulation(self.mainWindow)
        self.frameRenderer = FrameRenderer(self.simulation, self.graphicsScene)
        self.drawFood(self.foodSlider.sliderPosition())
        self.frameRenderer.start() 

    #toggle whether or not we are current simulating 
    def toggleSimulation(self):

        if not self.simulationStarted:
            return 

        if self.isSimulating:
            self.frameRenderer.pause()
        else:
            self.frameRenderer.start()

        self.isSimulating = not self.isSimulating

    #clear sim window
    def cancelSimulation(self):
        self.frameRenderer = None
        self.simulation = None
        self.createGraphicsScene()
        self.isSimulating = False 
        self.simulationStarted = False
```

The code works fine until I cancel then begin the simulation again. If I do that I get `RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem) already deleted.`. This is correct because I do create a new simulation object when begin is pressed but it is also passed to the constructor meaning it shouldn't be referencing my old simulation. I'm not sure why recreating the assets wont let me draw again

I've attempted explicitly setting frame renderer to None trying to put it out of scope but that doesn't seem to help

Comment: If you are using PySide2 then use that tag, PySide2 currently has many bugs that PyQt5 does not have. On the other hand it provides a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the graphics scene to `None` was not enough to trigger Qt to cause the underlying c++ deconstructor to run. In order to get the scene to be deleted I had to first empty the scene *then* delete it

```
for item in self.graphicsScene.items():
    self.graphicsScene.removeItem(item)
```